# Add new parameter in laravel 4.2 response on filter(registerOnAfter)

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-filters

Thanks in advance

I have used laravel filter and, now I wnat to add new parameter in response object, I am not able to add new parameter.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks for your kind rpl, I have solved it my own...